# Converting the update statement dynamically to select

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to convert an update statement to select statement dynamically in PL/SQL.

For example 
`update temp set b='apple' where a=1`
should be converted to 
`select count(*) from temp where a=1`

Comment: ..and why do you want to do that? The primary reason you thought let's go with this approach should be from something else. Tell us why did you arrive at deciding this. We'll try to provide a  solution to the original problem.

Comment: The requirement is that in my procedure which used to just update the table  dynamically should now also display the contents of the table with condition

Comment: So which part of this problem are you having trouble with? You have posted a static SQL statement so where does the *"dynamically"* fit in?

Comment: Without seeing the code for your procedure we have no basis for making a recommendation. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include sufficient code from your procedure so we can understand what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query is dynamic then you can try the following:

```
-- DATA PREPARATION
WITH MY_QUERY ( QRY ) AS (
    SELECT
        q'#update temp set b='apple' where a=1#'
    FROM
        DUAL
)
-- ACTUAL QUERY
SELECT
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
    || TABLENAME
    || ' '
    || WHERE_CLAUSE AS UPDATED_QUERY
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(QRY, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) AS TABLENAME,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(QRY, 'where (.)+$', 1, 1) AS WHERE_CLAUSE
        FROM
            MY_QUERY
    );


--
OUTPUT:
--
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp where a=1
```

Your query(String) is wrapped in an alternative quoted string(q'#....#') as it contains quotes.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=66346cc48130bd8808c18c54923861fe)

Comment: This is a massive guess regarding the OP's actual code and requirements.

Comment: I guess yes, But this is generic code. I have just removed SET condition. I think it will work for the @mani

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to dynamically modify SQL, or are you just looking to get the number of rows modified?  If you only need the number of rows modified, then `SQL%ROWCOUNT` can provide that:

```
create table temp as
select 1 a, 'orange' b from dual;

declare
    v_sql varchar2(32767) := q'[update temp set b='apple' where a=1]';
begin
    execute immediate v_sql;
    dbms_output.put_line('Rows updated: '||sql%rowcount);
end;
/
```

Output:

```
Rows updated: 1
```

---

If you really need to dynamically modify SQL, then you're in a world of pain.  Parsing SQL 100% correctly is almost impossible, unless you can guarantee that your input SQL will conform to a small range of values.

If you need to parse and reformat SQL, hopefully you can use regular expressions like in Tejash's answer.  If you need something more powerful, take a look at my open source program [PLSQL_LEXER](https://github.com/method5/plsql_lexer).  If you still need more power, then take a look at Antlr.  But as the solutions get more powerful they grow exponentially more complex.